Linux VMs suddenly booting up with no network connectivity - need to manually ifup to restore each boot up?
I have a Proxmox 8.3.2 hypervisor host, running several Linux VMs.
Recently, I opted in to the Proxmox 6.11 kernels (Default is 6.8 kernels).
Around that time, I noticed that after a reboot, the VMs would come up with no network connectivity - you would need to manually toggle the interface with ifup to get network connectivity. I originally attributed this to the 6.8 -> 6.11 kernel upgrade - however, even booting back into the 6.8 kernels, the issue persists. So now I'm really stumped. And some hosts, even this workaround doesn't work.
Just in case - here's the output of ip link on the Proxmox hypervisor host when booting into 6.8:
https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/582ea69a1c8ee9215e45bb805ff590e5
And the output of ip link when booting into 6.11 on the hypervisor host:
https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/4385bbeff0eb6489c85637a61df9aad4
From what I can tell, the only difference is the MAC addresses between them.
I have several Debian VMs, as well as an ArubaOS VM (which AFAIK is its own Linux variant) - they boot up with no connectivity, but if you do a manual ifup they seem to be able to get a DHCP lease successfully...
Here's the ip link output from one of the VMs:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:24:11:bd:a1:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp6s18
    altname enxbc2411bda1f8
3: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none

If I do sudo ifupdown ens18 it replies with ifup: unknown interface ens18. However, sudo ifup end6s18 does work - this successfully gets a DHCP lease
Here's the output of dmesg from that same VM as well:
https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/f66285d0ed3c94e6574f547549e9a2a1
There's a line in there:
[    1.100303] virtio_net virtio2 ens18: renamed from eth0

but I don't think that's the issue, right? (From Googling - this change was in systems 197, which was back in 2013 - https://lwn.net/Articles/531850/).
Here's the output of /etc/network/interfaces from that VM as well:
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp6s18
iface enp6s18 inet dhcp

The ArubaOS VM also doesn't have connectivity either, which is super confusing, since that system hasn't been updated in months - which is why I was thinking all of this was at the Proxmox/hypervisor level. But I can't figure it out...ugh.
Is there any way to find out why the machines are booting up with no network connectivity? Or try to figure out what's going on here?

Have run journalctl --boot on the VMs to see if there's any useful info in the boot-time logs? Or journalctl -boot --unit networking?  Or journalctl -boot | grep net? Etc.
